# Find the $\gcd(2k-1,9k+4)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

This is that I did so far.If $d=\gcd(2k-1,9k+4)$ then:

$d \mid 2k-1$ and $d \mid 9k+4$ so
$d \mid 2(9k+4)-9(2k-1)\implies d\mid 17$ so $d$ is $17$ for some values and $1$ for others.

After some observation I concluded that if $k=9+17n$ then $d=17$ and $d=1$ otherwise but I can’t prove it.  Any help will be appreciated

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: So you want to find which $k$ satisfy $17 \mid 2k-1$.In particular, you observe that this is true if and only if $ 17 \mid k - 9$. How can you work with that?

Comment: Hint : Try to find a solution to this$$d\equiv-1[2]\;and\;d\equiv4[9]$$

Comment: Easier and (more general) to use the slight generization of the Euclidean algorithm explained in the linked dupes, yielding gcd $= (2k-1,17).\,$  It's $> 1\!\iff\! \bmod 17\!:\ 2k\equiv 1\equiv 18\!\iff\! k\equiv 9\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Do the Euclidean algorithm: add/subtract copies of one slot of $\gcd(-,-)$ from the other.

$$
    \gcd(2k-1,9k+4) = \gcd(2k-1, 9k+4 - 4(2k-1)) = \gcd(2k-1, k+8) = \gcd(2k-1-2(k+8), k+8) = \gcd(-17, k+8).
$$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: Understood, I’ll try to avoid in the future. Thanks!